# try to fetch data from mysql based on value on android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, compiler-errors

I'm not sure about where is the error , I have a value and want to fetch data from mysql data based on this value but getting many errors, I think it's not passing the value , here is my code

```
class GetExtended extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int sucess;
    try {
        NotificationID="2";
        List<NameValuePair> Ext = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        Ext.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NotificationID", NotificationID));
        json3 = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(Get_Ext,"POST", Ext);

        sucess = json3.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (sucess == 1) {
            getExt = json3.getString("FieldTitle");
            //getExtVal =json3.getString("FieldValue");

            return json.getString("succ");


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


    return getExt ;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String getExt){

    try {

        JSONObject json3; 
        Rec2 = new JSONArray(result);
        name2 = new String[Rec2.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<Rec2.length();i++){

        json3 = Rec2.getJSONObject(i);
        name2[i] = json3.getString("FieldTitle");
        }

        for (int i=0; i<name2.length; i++){
        list2.add(name2[i]);
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  name2[0] , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here my PHP code

```
    <?php

define("DB_HOST", "server name.com");

define("DB_USER", "username");

define("DB_PASSWORD", "Ab234");

define("DB_DATABASE", "dbname");
$NotificationID=$_POST["NotificationID"] ;
if (empty($_POST['NotificationID']))
{
$response["success"] = 0; 
$response["message"] = "the field is empty .";

}
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
$sql1=mysql_query("select * from aov_noti_ExtendedInfo where NotificationID = '$NotificationID'" 
,  $conn); 

$json = array(); 

if (mysql_num_rows($sql1)) { 

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Your data success to load";
   while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
            $json['aov_noti_ExtendedInfo'][]=$row;
} 

} 

mysql_close($conn);
echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

also this is my logcat

```
03-09 20:36:28.109: W/System.err(1120): org.json.JSONException: No value for FieldTitle
03-09 20:36:28.118: W/System.err(1120):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
03-09 20:36:28.118: W/System.err(1120):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
03-09 20:36:28.128: W/System.err(1120):     at com.example.notifier.Notifications$GetExtended.onPostExecute(Notifications.java:460)
03-09 20:36:28.128: W/System.err(1120):     at com.example.notifier.Notifications$GetExtended.onPostExecute(Notifications.java:1)
03-09 20:36:28.128: W/System.err(1120):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-09 20:36:28.138: W/System.err(1120):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-09 20:36:28.138: W/System.err(1120):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-09 20:36:28.148: W/System.err(1120):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 20:36:28.148: W/System.err(1120):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-09 20:36:28.158: W/System.err(1120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-09 20:36:28.158: W/System.err(1120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 20:36:28.168: W/System.err(1120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 20:36:28.168: W/System.err(1120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-09 20:36:28.188: W/System.err(1120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-09 20:36:28.188: W/System.err(1120):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

anybody help me pleeeeaase?

Comment: It simply means there is either no field with name `FieldTitle` in your JSONArray or your JSONArray is malformed. Try to check result of query by using a Log.d() statement

Comment: @SouravKanta in which part please , i'm new in android , thanks :)

Comment: Try Log.d("Check", result) in your postExcecute() and see what output you get and if there is a field called FieldTitle

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql1=mysql_query("select * from aov_noti_ExtendedInfo where NotificationID = '$NotificationID'"
```

to

```
$sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aov_noti_ExtendedInfo WHERE NotificationID = '$NotificationID'"
```

Comment: thanks for replay but I got that error : 
03-09 21:10:55.618: E/JSON Parser(1325): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-09 21:10:55.628: W/System.err(1325): org.json.JSONException: No value for FieldTitle

Comment: Try what Sourav Kanta says. You will find the solution faster like that